# How to make my if statement simpler and more elegant

Tags: if-statement

I am a new learner to python programming. I'm just making pizza order program but I feel like I could make it better - what can I improve?

```
if size == "S" and add_pepperoni == "Y" and extra_cheese == "Y":
    
     total += 18

elif size == "S" and add_pepperoni == "N" and extra_cheese == "Y":
     
    total += 16

elif size == "S" and add_pepperoni == "N" and extra_cheese == "N":

    total += 15

elif size == "S" and add_pepperoni == "Y" and extra_cheese =="N":
    
    total += 17
```

Answer (score 0):

you are essentially asking how you can simplify your logic for calculating the price ? If that is the case, i feel some more information would be needed to optimize this. But in general it could be simpler if you can break it down into separate decisions and add an amount to the total based on the outcome of each decision. For example:
if size == "S":
total += 15
end

if add_pepperoni == "Y":
total += 2
end

if extra_cheese == "Y":
total += 1
end

essentially you only add to the total if something is selected.

It's just another of doing it, there can be even better ways to write any logic as such. To generalise, break it down and solve it 1 by 1.